# Iterate two objects in for loop python

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to iterate two object with same range in for loop, however, it shows an error with

```
for (s,s1) in range (5000,10000):
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

My code is :

```
(fs, data)=wav.read('13.wav')
frq, X = frequency_sepectrum(data, fs)

y=butter_highpass_filter(data,3000, fs, order=5)        
frqs, Y = frequency_sepectrum(y, fs)

s = set (frq)
s1 = set (frqs)
for (s,s1) in range (5000,10000):
    if (X[s]> 10 and Y[s1]>100):
        print ('yes')
        break
```

Comment: You just want `for x, y in zip(X, Y): ... ` although note, in your case, you could just *re-use `s`*

Comment: @  juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for your reply. I think the problem is occurred in line  `for (s,s1) in range (5000,10000):`  Do you mean change it to for `s,s1 in zip(s, s1): `?

Comment: what values do you expect `s` and `s1` should have in the first iteration? If the same, then you dont need two variables. If two different values, then you might misunderstand how `range()` works. Which one is it?

Comment: @ yedpodtrzitko Hi, s and s1 are two very large arrays. I want to ensure that s and s1 do have values in range from 5k to 10k. Then, I need to find out the corresponding X and Y values in respect of s and s1

Comment: What module is `frequency_spectrum` from?

Comment: @catalogue_number  `def frequency_sepectrum(x, sf):

    x = x - np.average(x)  # zero-centering
    n = len(x)
    print(n)
    k = arange(n)
    tarr = n / float(sf)
    frqarr = k / float(tarr)  # two sides frequency range
    frqarr = frqarr[range(n // 2)]  # one side frequency range
    x = scipy.fft.fft(x) / n  # fft computing and normalization
    x = x[range(n // 2)]
    return frqarr, abs(x)`

Comment: Just fyi, when asking questions like this make sure to include all modules used and the definitions of relevant functions in the question itself.

Comment: This logic doesn't make sense. One approach that might work for you is dropping all the values from your frequencies that you don't want. It looks like you might also want to only use values that are both in s and s1?

Comment: @Cireo Yes, s1 undergoes high pass filtering, in this case the corresponding signal value Y may be different compared to unfiltered X. So, I need to compare them from 5K to 10K. Then, setting a if statement if the certain values are greater than 10 or 100 or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's unpack the construction `for obj in iterable:`

Python expects `iterable` to be, in a sense, 'list-like': a list, dictionary or similar. On every loop iteration, `obj` takes the value of the "next" thing in `iterable`. Here, your `iterable` is `range(5000,10000)`, which refers to the sequence 5000, 5001, 5002, ..., 9999. Your code is erroring because there's no sensible way to set a 2-tuple, `(s,s1)` to a number, e.g. 5000.

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve, but assuming that you only want to examine *frequencies between 5000 and 10000*, i.e. *only those entries where* `frq[i] > 5000 && frq[i] < 10000`, you need to do something else.

```py
import numpy as np

(fs, data)=wav.read('13.wav')
frq, X = frequency_sepectrum(data, fs)

y=butter_highpass_filter(data,3000, fs, order=5)        
frqs, Y = frequency_sepectrum(y, fs)

# optional check for if frq, frqs are the same (I assume they are)
for f1, f2 in zip(frq, frqs):
    if f1 != f2:
        print("Frequency grids do not agree.")

# Find the indices of the boundary frequencies,
# assuming that frqs is in ascending order
min_idx = np.searchsorted(frqs, 5000)
max_idx = np.searchsorted(frqs, 10000)

# chop off the extraneous values
frqs = frqs[min_idx : max_idx]
X = X[min_idx : max_idx]
Y = Y[min_idx : max_idx]

# O(n) loop to check for first (lowest-frequency) occurrence of X>10, Y>100
for f, x, y in zip(frq, X, Y):
    if (x> 10 and y>100):
        print ('yes, found at frequency f=', f)
        break
```

Explanation:

`zip(frq, frqs)` glues the two vectors together, making a single vector of tuples, think of these like `[( , ), ( , ), ( , ), ...]`

`for f1, f2 in zip(frq, frqs)` sets f1 to the value that `frq` had, and f2 to the value that `frqs` had on each loop iteration

The lower loop does the same thing, but with three vectors glued together.

Note that this will fail/behave unexpectedly if any of `X, Y, frq, frqs` has a different length to the others.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried my solution:

```
s = set (frq)
s1 = set (frqs)
for s in range(5000,10000):
    for s1 in range (5000,10000):
        if (X[s]> 10 and Y[s1]>100):
            print ('yes')
            break
```

It takes bit long time to run, so I am wondering is there any way to save the execution time?